# PDF Invoice; changing shipping and other text

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I am creating a new PDF Invoice and most is fine but the one thing that I just cannot find is how to change the text of the 'totals' block at the end!

Currently this shows

```
Subtotal
Shipping & Handling
Grand Total
```

and I want it to show

```
Sub Total
Delivery
Total
```

Should be very easy and I expected to be able to overwrite the values in my local locale translate.csv file with an entry such as

```
"Shipping & Handling","Delivery"
```

but it doesn't work!

Cache cleared, etc. but no change on the invoice.  What am I missing?

Or can anyone tell me how to get these values from the order so I can craft the lines myself?

Magento 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 3):

These Labels are coming from Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml between line 1443 and 1480
I am not sure where in the admin section they are present, if they are present there.

But you can always change them from .csv files

For example, I did it from here

app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv

like this

```
"Shipping & Handling","Delivery"
"Shipping &amp; Handling","Delivery"
```

You need to do it for your own language.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd alreasdy tried changing the values as suggested in app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv but nothing changed.  I've got country set to United Kingdom which, as I understand it, uses 'en_US'.

I notice also that the theme I'm using has a translate.csv file which seems to be being ignored.  It may be in some strange way connected.

Comment: Did you flush the cache?

Answer (score 3):

Go `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\locale\en_US`

translate.csv

Add your text where u want to change first column Shipping & Handling  second column on you want a text.

Add your label translate list on this file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can see that yours clearly worked but mine doesn't!  I'd already tried and overwrite in `app\design\adminhtml\default\mytheme\locale\en_US` and that hadn't worked so I was a bit excited that your answer would have hit on the answer I needed but there must be something else strange going on!  :-(

Comment: I changed the core file `code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml` and the changes I want show up, but when I try to do it by overwriting, having a copy in `code/local/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml` and changing it there, it doesn't work.  Is that not the right way to change things?  I'd really rather not change core files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override it, don't use

```
"Subtotal","Sub Total"
```

Use it like this

```
"Mage_Sales::Subtotal","Sub Total"
```

Since this translation is located in the `Mage_Sales.csv` file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I couldn't see the changes afer i added translation to translate.csv

If you change translate.csv in directory below

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\locale\en_US
```

Make sure your locale option in Settings is set to the English US rather than English UK that was my mistake.