# Override Adminhtml Translation file with Module

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, pdf, localisation, language

I am using Magento ce-1.9.2.1 in my site.

It is mainly in nb_NO(Norwegian) language, even in admin panel.

Now I want to add a custom translation file in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/nb_NO` - by name `Package_Module.csv` but with a custom module.

I can't figure out the settings for this in my module's `config.xml` and the path related stuff.

Please help anyone.

Answer (score 3):

follow [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-your-own-translations-to-custom-modules/) tutorial.add your translation file `app/locale/en_US/` here. you can add this for `frontend`

```
<frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <translations>
                    <files>
                        <default>Translations.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </translations>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
```

for `admin panel`

```
 <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <translations>
                    <files>
                        <default>Translations.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </translations>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
```

Comment: Ok I will try it, moreover I am trying to change translation of whole "Subtotal" section in printed invoice-pdf, but it's not working even with adminhtml translate.csv file of nb_NO locale, can you suggest anything for it ?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42111/pdf-invoice-changing-shipping-and-other-text follow this

Comment: Followed it but didn't help, I also changed the text in "Mage_Sales.csv" of nb_NO(Norsk Bokmål)(just for testing) directly but still no effect on translation. Please help it's urgent.

Comment: did you refresh the cache after it?

Comment: Yes I did, but still same thing.

Comment: did you change in current language locale?

Comment: Admin is already in "nb_NO(Norsk Bokmål)" mode, all the text are translated even in PDF, but just the subtotal block is in english in print pdf.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30244/discussion-between-vicky-dev-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: The string you try to translate in the invoice is probably not taken from `Mage_Sales` but `Mage_Tax` or another module. To understand translation scope, read: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/how-to-implement-translations-in-design-template-package-csvs-how-does-echo-t/78483#78483